# RichTextBox SelectionLength changing weird when dragging mouse up

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

After placing a RichTextBox in a form (using VS 2008 and using default values), I can enter text and select it all whether dragging mouse from start to end or first selecting the end of text and dragging to the beginning. However, if I set the RichTextBox SelectionStart property in the SelectionChanged to its value, the selection is not highlighted properly when dragging from the end of entered text to the beginning. It highlights (selects) one word at a time. Why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // With this line, text is not selected properly with dragging "up".
            // It is selected when dragging down.  Why?
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that line? Without it would you have a problem? Have you tried break pointing on that line and examining the `SelectionStart` value (or print it to console) when dragging upwards? Maybe that value changes when you drag upwards - what was the original start point actually becomes the end point?

Comment: This code is the simplest code that demonstrate the issue.  What I am attempting is to examine the text during the event to determine the styling of the fonts in order to set the state of the style buttons (similiar to Wordpad).  As shown in code below, I would save the SelectionStart and SelectionLength on entering the event handler and then reset to the original values when exiting.  I narrowed the problem down to setting the SelectionStart to the same value (as demonstrated by the one line of code).

Comment: I also want to mention that I did check watch SelectionStart and SelectionLength.  SelectionStart appear to track properly - but SelectionLength changes (typically to the size of the word).